# Opening explorer from bash/linux subsystem in Windows 10

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-10

Is there a command to open the current directory in windows file explorer from bash (or zsh) using bash on ubuntu on windows? I think I saw somewhere you can do `explorer .` but it tells me `No command 'explorer' found`

Comment: Do not copy from windows to WSL from windows explorer. Do not use windows explorer to open files within WSL in a native windows program and save them back to the original location within WSL (the files will disappear from WSL because windows has no concept of Unix file permissions). You can look at the files in WSL, but do not modify them except from within WSL itself.

Comment: Woah what? I thought WSL accessed the same files. If I navigate to /mnt/d/mydocuments and edit something with vim or nano, and later open the same file from explorer, there will be issues?

Comment: **Oh no no no...** You can access the same files, but linux file permission were never made part of WSL. So if you use any editor or the windows side to open files in WSL and then save them -- poof, they vanish from WSL. Now you can *make a copy* of the file from WSL on the windows side, edit as you like, then copy back to WSL **from within WSL** (e.g. `cp /mnt/c/path/to/file/you/edited destination`) but you can't save it from say notepad++ to e.g. `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\lxss` **--Poof!**

Comment: Man, that seems so bizarre to me. Why give us access to windows files in WSL if this issue exists? I was under the impression this was like having bash with windows, working side by side to conquer evil! How disappointing

Comment: What it does is make you really learn *vim* or *emacs* `:)`  You can also load an X-window and use any gui that way. It's not that much of a limitation, but it can bite you if you are not careful. (note, when the file goes **Poof!** it still exists, Linux just can't see it.) Here is a link [**Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Comment: Dude thank you for mentioning that. I'm actually learning vim right now and loving it. You've restored my hope.

Comment: Although, I am working on a Unity project, and I'm not sure how well it lends itself to vim, or vice versa :(

Comment: `vim` is really the swiss army knife of editors. It's just like anything, you have to pay the price to learn it. Really learn it... You can always get around in it, but being able to really use it takes sticking with it. I admit, my editor is KDE3/kwrite (or kate), but I use `vim` enough to be proficient. I'll spend a week or using vim exclusively, filling in the gaps in my proficiency as I go, then I go back to kwrite -- and have to do it all over again 6 months later... (it's not that bad, but "if you play golf, your tennis game with suffer...") WSL works great, just takes a bit of time.

Comment: Wait a sec. I just read that link and it basically says editing files in the windows file system from linux is fine. So I can edit files from bash that are in /mnt/c or /mnt/d (my hdd) without worries. I just shouldn't edit linux files from windows. _To work on files using both Windows and Linux tools, store & work on those files in your Windows filesystem, and access them from both Windows and from Bash via /mnt/<drive>/path (e.g. /mnt/c/dev/project/...)_

Comment: Yes, you can edit files **in the windows filesystem from Linux** but you **cannot** edit files **in the Linux filesystem from windows**. (**Poof!**) The *blog.msdn* posts play a little 'cute' with the issue to avoid flat-out calling attention to the short-fall. It's like msdn is a damn *politician* in that regard... (You have to really sort out what they are saying to keep from being duped...)

Comment: The ultimate IDE is `vim` + `tmux`. You can generate any structure of windows and panes that you wish and access everything through command line in Vim and Bash. Once you've gone through the learning curve you will never ever be mortal again. It can be lonely at times at the top, but it's worth it, and when you meet a friend perchance on a journey you will have found a brother, @EthanFischer.

Comment: @EthanFischer: "Why give us access to windows files in WSL if this issue exists?" - because Windows is incapable. It will always have issues. The best you can do is try to get as much distance from it as possible. Organisations who rely on Windows are basically leveraging a large pool of (to put it politely) (Microsoft trained) "point and click talent", and their minds are closed to reality. Windows has tried to make concessions because Linux is dominating automated infrastructure, and they're trying to cover up their "open source is evil" past, but Window$ is still Windoze.

Answer (score 20):

Since the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, you can now [directly run Windows executables from Bash/WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/interop). Try updating Windows through Windows update, and then run the following in Bash:

```
$ explorer.exe .
```

Alternatively,

```
$ /mnt/c/Windows/explorer.exe .
```

(where `c` is the drive of your Windows installation`). This will open a new Explorer window in the current directory.

Comment: explorer.exe . opens up C:\Windows\System32 for me.  But it's not the current directory

Comment: @techguy2000 - it works for me - I installed Ubuntu for my linux subsystem

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 with latest updates. I see either the System32 folder, or My Documents, any time I try to open a folder inside Ubuntu. If it's a folder on one of my Windows drives, it works fine.

Comment: The alternative methods works for me! Ubuntu 18.04 and WSL2 build 2004 19041

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me on my GIT bash on windows 10.

```
$ which explorer
/c/Windows/explorer
$ explorer .
```

Comment: hmm, I'm not using GIT bash though. I'm using the linux subsystem feature (beta)

Comment: Sure. Can you try my suggestion?

Comment: Haha yep. I will try it later today. Thanks

Comment: When I run `which explorer` in WSL, it says `explorer not found`. When I run it in git bash, it works.

Comment: Recall, `which` only searches your `PATH`. Unless you have `/mnt/c/Windows` in your path, `which` won't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get $ /mnt/c/Windows/explorer.exe . to work for me. What worked for me was installing [Search Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) and using it to search for a file in the current directory. You can then right-click the file in the results and hit Open Path.

Answer (score 0):

Running this command below, you can create a Symlink which you can refer by `/explorer.exe`

`sudo ln -s /mnt/c/Windows/explorer.exe explorer.exe`

Now run:

`/explorer.exe .`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using zsh, you can try:

```
$ echo 'alias <your alias|open>="/mnt/c/Windows/explorer.exe"' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
```

bash:

```
$ echo 'alias <your alias|open>="/mnt/c/Windows/explorer.exe"' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Then only you can do:

```
 $ <your alias|open> path
```

Answer (score 0):

explorer.exe won't work due to the mounting privileges but there is an alternative way that might work most of the time.
you can install xdg-utils and after the installation, you just need to command in terminal 'xdg-open .' which '.' indicate the directory you wish to pop up.

in Ubuntu distro:

```
$ sudo apt install xdg-utils
```

and then

```
$ xdg-open .
```